# UICollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath crash in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

Please guide me something about path.

```
 NSIndexPath *index = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]objectAtIndex:0];
    _assetVersion = assetVer;
    _bookPosition = [[bookList objectAtIndex:index.row]bookPosition];
    _bookId = [[bookList objectAtIndex:index.row]bookID];
    bookPath = [[bookList objectAtIndex:index.row]bookPath];
    _downloadURLbook = [[bookList objectAtIndex:index.row]downloadURL];
    NSLog(@"%@",_bookPosition);

    cell.bookId = _bookId;
      NSLog(@"%@",bookPath);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{     
            NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://powershelf-dev.3viewsolution.com/dhl/webservice/book_extract.php?main_menu=%@&language=%@&id=%@",_checkType,_checkLang,(_bookPosition)];
            NSURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
            NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]init];
            NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
            [self connection:urlConnection didReceiveResponse:response];
            [self connection:urlConnection didReceiveData:data];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            //code for check data

            });
    });
```

I don't know this one why alway crash like this

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DownloadedBookDetail bookPosition]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146cf4a0'
```

But when i go with image from web service it's work. if i use `bookIndex = indexPath;` without  code

```
NSIndexPath *index = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]objectAtIndex:0];
        _assetVersion = assetVer;
        _bookPosition = [[bookList objectAtIndex:index.row]bookPosition];
        _bookId = [[bookList objectAtIndex:index.row]bookID];
        bookPath = [[bookList objectAtIndex:index.row]bookPath];
        _downloadURLbook = [[bookList objectAtIndex:index.row]downloadURL];
```

it's will work also. But i need to use data from database check data with Web service.
I need to use `bookIndex = indexPath;` with web service 
I'm go check with this

```
if([db isDownloaded:bookName bookVersion:[bookVersion floatValue]]){    
                        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"reader" sender:self];
                    }
                    else{
                        [self startDownload];
                    }
```

Thanks for any Idea.

Comment: On `_bookPosition = [[bookList objectAtIndex:index.row]bookPosition];` Print out what the value of this `[bookList objectAtIndex:index.row]` or maybe try printing out the class of that object.

Comment: It looks like [bookList objectAtIndex:index.row] is of type *DownloadedBookDetail* which is either wrong according to your logic or  if it is not wrong then you may not have imported the class before use.